# Update $scope from external javascript plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a javascript plugin that convert persian date . everything works well except one thing .
I've added a default value for input like : `$scope.myDate='13930101' ;`

But i'd like to update it when user click on new date . How can i update the $scope ? should i create a directive for that ?
Thanks

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWNUv6Qvnqj1VW8naOuB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This is the really nice thing about Angular, you don't have to watch simple variables to update them in the $scope. Take out `ng-change="newDate()"` on your date field. When you use ng-model on an input field, any changes made to that input field will be reflected in the variable you set it to.

The other thing you can do is move your onClick function into the angular ng-click function you created:

```
$scope.showDate = function() {
  // alert($scope.myDate);
  PersianDatePicker.Show('thisDate', $scope.myDate);
};
```

That will grab the current value of $scope.myDate and pass it into the plugin:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYsyn9rqItmqaZXhHcrI?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the tips , but how can i check the new value of $scope.MyDate ?
and i want to pass the new value to database

Comment: You'll want to `$watch` the variable, and run an angular function that saves the data to the DB: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch

Comment: sry, didn't get you ,can you tell me how to see the new value of $scope.myDate